# how to use PuTTY's PLINK with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssh, putty, plink

i am trying to develop a browser based interface with node.js to execute commands on remote servers, same as PuTTY on browser. is there any library available or something for a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) which is implemented in pure javascript for node.